# Not on earth at the judgement day?

Tags: day-of-judgement

Salam,

A question about Al qiyamah, we Know from Quran and Hadith that it will be earthquakes etc.. but what will happen to spacemen out of the planet ?

Comment: The whole universe will be destroyed on Qiyamah according to plenty of description in the Quran and hadith.

Comment: An important part of Islamic eschatology is that during the end times, there will be a great war (Malhama) which will be so intense that after it all the wars will be fought only with swords and stones. One possible explanation given by contemporary scholars is that this could be a nuclear war after which almost all our modern technology will be destroyed ... we would go back to living how we did a few centuries ago due to the immense destruction caused and the lack of resources ... so perhaps no humans in space at that time ... Allah  knows best

Answer (score 0):

Doesn’t really matter. Every single human being, on Earth or not, will be judged by Allah.
I don’t even think that there will be people outside of Earth before the day of judgement. (Surat Ar-Rahman; a meteorite made of copper will destroy the humans or djinns who will try to leave Earth permanently).